# Is there any alternative for Document.visibilityState in WebAPI?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webapi

I have a mini app that will run inside another app. This mini app will run as an iFrame inside the "parent" app (running on mobile: Android and iOS).

I am trying to get the mini app to show a popup whenever the Back Key pressed, but somehow it fails. I though that when the back key pressed it will registered on the parents app, thus the visibilitychange will be valid.

Below is the code I use:

```
RegisterVisibilityChange()
{
    var hidden, visibilityChange; 
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") 
    { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support 
        hidden = "hidden";
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
    } 
    else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") 
    {
        hidden = "msHidden";
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
    } 
    else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") 
    {
        hidden = "webkitHidden";
        visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
    }

    function handleVisibilityChange() {
        if (document[hidden]) {
            window.onGamePause();
        } else {
            window.onGameResume();
        }
    }

    // Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
    if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || hidden === undefined) 
    {
        Utils.AddLogText("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Handle page visibility change   
        document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
    }
}
```

is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "back key"? Backspace? The browser's "back" button? Something else?

Comment: device/phone's back key in android. The one use for navigating to previous page.

Comment: Question is good. It is nice to have vanilla solution for ECMA5 or less.